# Values obtained in case of a recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, static-variables

Can anyone explain to me the reason behind the output of this program to be `0 0 0 0 0`?

Here we are using a `static variable var` whose values will not change due to function calls. The values of `var` will be `4, 3, 2, 1` during the recursive calls. When `var` becomes zero the recursion terminates and control moves on to the `printf` statement.

Why is the output not `1,2,3,4`?

```
 main(){ 
      static int var=5;
      if(--var)
        main();
      printf(" %d ",var);
 }
```

Again if you use if condition `var--` then program output will be `-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1`?

Comment: About 2-nd question: `--var` decrements first and then checks for `if(var)`, while `var--` checks the value of var and then decrements. `if(var--)` means `if(var) var = var - 1;` and `if(--var)` : `var = var - 1; if(var)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your recursion call `printf()` executes when `main()` returns. And because `var` is a `static variable` its value remain `0` (last value = 0 same for all function call)

Note `if()` condition false when `var` becomes `0` (last value, after  main(); call you don't change var - notice diagram).

Hope following diagram will help you to understand (read comments):

```
main() <---------------+
{                      |
  static int var=5;    | <----"Declared only one/first time with value 5"
  if(--var)            |
 ---- main(); ---------+ // called if var != 0 
 |             // main called for var = 4, 3, 2, 1  
 |// recursion stooped     
 |// return with 0 value 
 |// now no operation applied on `var` so it remain 0 
 +--> printf(" %d ",var);  // called when return ed  
}
```

Remainder life of static function is till program terminates (so values not loss),  and Scope is within function.

> [**14.1.6 Static Variables**](http://ee.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap14/subsection2.1.1.6.html)
>
> The scope of static automatic variables is identical to that of
>   automatic variables, i.e. it is local to the block in which it is
>   defined; however, the storage allocated becomes permanent for the
>   duration of the program. Static variables may be initialized in their
>   declarations; however, **the initializers must be constant expressions,
>   and initialization is done only once at compile time when memory is
>   allocated for the static variable***.

**Second question:**

> Again if you use `var--` then your output will be `-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1`?

Suppose if your condition will be `var--` then `if()` condition fist checks `true` or `false` before decrement `--`. (because in expression `var--`, `--` is postfix).
And because `if()` breaks when `var` == `0` then recursive call stops and function returns with decremented value from `0` to `-1`. And because after return `var` doesn't change hence output is `-1` for all.

Comment: That must be it. The printf are called after all recursions (as well as subtractions) are finished

Comment: @MyPasswordIsLasercats yes check the diagram

Comment: Worth noting that the real problem here with respect to observed/expected output is that the variable is static, meaning it is the same variable across recursive calls. A modified code with a local variable and a couple modifications would produce the expected output.

Comment: Ok.Got it.Thanks Grijesh Chauhan.

Comment: @C_beginner but wait if I can add some more helpful informations ..Thomas has good suggestion

Comment: @Thomas No if I remove static then `var` will declare every time and if condition will be `4` for all function call so it struct in infinite loop.

Comment: @C_beginner do you understands that if you remove static it would be in infinite loop **?**

Comment: Yes,if the static is removed then everytime the variable will get declared and initialised when main is called,ultimately an infinite loop.Program is getting terminated also in that case.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan "*and a couple modifications*"

Comment: @C_beginner ok do you wants I give you a code that outputs `4 3 2 1 0` ?? it would be tough for me as well because you are using main() function and its syntax is fixed

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan No thanks.In some recursive functions I noticed the values got printed in descending order after the exit of the recursive call but of course static variables and main() function were not used in those cases.

Answer (score 2):

> The values of var will be `4, 3, 2, 1` during the recursive calls. When var
>   becomes zero the recursion terminates and control moves on to the
>   `printf()` statement.Why is the output not `1, 2, 3, 4`?

A static variable is a variable that has been allocated statically—whose lifetime or "extent" extends across the entire run of the program.

So the value of var changes every time and at  last it becomes `0` and `printf()` executes after the return of main and as the value of var is `0` ,every `printf()` statement will print `0`.

Answer (score 1):

**Static variables** are those variables  whose **life time** remains equal to the life time of the program.Static variables get are initialized **once**. The value of the variable will change after every system call . If you had not declared the variable as static there would have been an infinite recursion resulting in an **segmentation fault** .