# How does the print statement gets executed four times here?

Tags: c, recursion, static

Until the value of `i` remains greater than 0 the `main()` is called recursively. Once it becomes `0` the if condition is violated. Anyone tell me how the print statement is executed. When I run it, I get the output `0000`. Thanks

```
void main()
{
    static int i=5;
    if(--i)
    {
        main();
        printf("%d",i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Read: [Values obtained in case of a recursive function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785765/values-obtained-in-case-of-a-recursive-function/17785800#17785800)

Answer (score 7):

```
i = 4
call main()
    i = 3
    call main()
        i=2 
        call main()
            i=1
            call main()
                i=0
            print 0
         print 0
    print 0
print 0
```

Remember that `i` is `static`, so it is common to all calls of the function.

Comment: i can understand the static part but why is the print statement executed 4 times?

Comment: @user1870724 what confuses you exactly? My example shows the 4 prints exactly where and when and why it happens.

Comment: I thought the print statement will be called only once.That is confusing me. I am not clear about the control flow.

Answer (score 0):

local static variable will store the newest modified value. Because you invoke main() recursively, `static i` will change from 4 to 0, after i become 0, it will stop to call main() and return to above level, then printf 0 (i is 0 now).