# Why does this program not run infinitely?

Tags: c, printf

Shouldn't this program run infinitely because main is being called every time? And why it's output is `0 0 0 0`? I know it's a noob question but I am not able to get it. What `--i` do and what is the effect of declaring i as static?

```
int main()
{
    static int i=5;
    if(--i){
        main();
        printf("%d ",i);
    }  
}
```

Comment: Read: [Values obtained in case of a recursive function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785765/values-obtained-in-case-of-a-recursive-function/17785800#17785800)

Comment: Is your question really "what does `--i` mean?", rather than "why does this not run infinitely?"?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Hi, no I know what does --i mean. I wanted to know how using it with if conditions works? Does it runs till i becomes 0?

Comment: No, it works recursively, and only works because `i` is a `static int`.

Comment: "What --i do and what is the effect of declaring i as static?" - perhaps read the language specification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The `static int` is not reinitialized each time.  Thus, each time main() is called, i is one lower.
2. when `(--i)` is zero, the recursive loop terminates.

Thus, it starts off with `i=5`, and calls a new copy.  This one has `i=4`, which again calls a new copy.  This continues until `i=0`, at which point the function just terminates.  Control flow is then returned up the call stack, and each copy of `main` prints `i`, which is now 0.  4 copies means 4 zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does not run forever is because at some point `i` becomes 0 and no longer calls main.  The trick is `static` which references the same memory location and hence is decremented each time `main` is recursively called.